# what will happen when one of ElasticSearch server down

Tags: elasticsearch, high-availability, failover

For example I have three machines, each machine with one shard and each shard with one replication. So there are 3 primary shards and 3 replicates. Right now one machine is down(power off). What will happen for the rest of two machines.
I think the data is still correct because we have replicates. but it lost one primary shard and one replication. So will the rest servers rebalance the data, I mean will it fill/recover the lost data in the rest servers?

And what will happen if the down server is up just after one minute? How will ES treat the old/lost data?

Comment: You will still have your data if your replicas are on the right nodes. The replica of the primary shard you lost will be promoted to primary. Your cluster health will drop to yellow, but all of your data will be searchable.

Comment: Thanks Ian, what will happen when the replicates are promoting but the lost primary shard are back.

Comment: The lost primary shards will be a replica when the node is back. The current primary shard will not be downgraded.